# DataBaseObjectNotClosedException while populate list view from SQLite in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

enter image description hereI'm really confused where is database object not closed.I'm trying to populate the listview from SQLite .When i run the List view is Empty and getting exception.

Can some one help me to sort out where is the problem.Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my code

```
public class Employee_List extends Activity
{

    Context mContext;
    Employee emp;

    ImageView imgButtonBack;

    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listEmployee;
     SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

 public static final String EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE = "employee_details";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staff_employee_list);
        listEmployee = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        showList();
    }

    private void showList()
    {     

    ArrayList<Employee> EmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    EmployeeList.clear();  

    String strQuery = "SELECT sum(empid) as emp_id, Staff_emp_name as emp_name, department as emp_dept, designation as emp_designation,"
                    +" (SUM(performance_rate_one+performance_rate_two+performance_rate_three+performance_rate_four+performance_rate_five)/5) as TotalPerformance"
                    +" FROM employee_details INNER JOIN performance"
                    +" ON employee_details.Emp_id = performance.empid "
                    +" GROUP BY empid "
                    +" ORDER BY TotalPerformance DESC";

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(strQuery, null);


    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
    {   
        if (c1.moveToFirst())

        {   
            do
            {    
                Employee EmployeeListItems = new Employee();  
                EmployeeListItems.setEmployeeId(c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_id")));
                EmployeeListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_name")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDepartment(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_dept")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDesignation(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("emp_designation")));

                EmployeeListItems.setPerformancerate(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("TotalPerformance")));
                EmployeeList.add(EmployeeListItems);     

            }while (c1.moveToNext());   
            c1.close();
            sqlDatabase.close();

        } 

    } 

    EmployeeList_Adapter contactListAdapter = new EmployeeList_Adapter(Employee_List.this, EmployeeList); 
    listEmployee.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);  
    //contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

ListAdapter Class

```
public class EmployeeList_Adapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            Context context;
            ArrayList<Employee> Employee_List;
            public EmployeeList_Adapter(Context context,
                    ArrayList<Employee> employee_List) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
                Employee_List = employee_List;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return Employee_List.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return Employee_List.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Employee EmployeeListItems = Employee_List.get(position);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.staff_employee_list_item, null);
                }


                TextView tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_emp_Id);
                tvID.setText(EmployeeListItems.getEmployeeId()+"");

                ImageView imgProfile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgStaff_Emp);


                TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_ame);
                tvName.setText(EmployeeListItems.getName());

                TextView tvDepartment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_Department);
                tvDepartment.setText(EmployeeListItems.getDepartment());


                TextView tvDesignation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_Designation);
                tvDesignation.setText(EmployeeListItems.getDesignation());


                TextView tvPerformanceRate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.empLoyeeRate);
                tvPerformanceRate.setText(EmployeeListItems.getPerformancerate());

                final Employee empPOsition = Employee_List.get(position);
                int positionA = Employee_List.indexOf(empPOsition);
                System.out.println(" empPOsition = " + positionA);

                return convertView;
            }

        }
```

Here is Log Cat INfo

```
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.sqlitedemo/databases/EmployeeReview.db' 
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at com.sqlitedemo.Employee_List.showList(Employee_List.java:147)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at com.sqlitedemo.Employee_List.onCreate(Employee_List.java:62)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-16 10:36:41.691: E/Database(383):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't open your database every time you are setting up your list , open your db first in your app startup. assume that if the if statement for closing db doesn't run so on setting up the list again it will raise error because of you are opening an already open database again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry but i didn't get you.

Comment: @jvd : see the edited answer , you are closing the db in an if statement which may not be run so , you are opening an already opened db again which will cause that error.